# node express cannot GET static content

Tags: node.js, express, static

Im running a node app inside of /opt/myapp directory.
I have haproxy in front content switching on path_beg /myapp
backend server is listening on port 3000

directory structure:

```
/opt/myapp
    index.js
    package, modules
    static
       public
          myfile.html


    const express = require("express");
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on 3000 "+__dirname+"  "+process.cwd()));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/static/public'));  //nope
    //app.use(express.static('..'+'/static/public')); //nope
    //app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static/public/')));  //nope
```

Where __dirname outputs /opt/myapp and process.cwd() outputs /opt/myapp

I tried both concantenation and path.join with same results. Cannot GET myfile.html

curl directly on the server to http://host.com:3000 does work by returning the page,
but from browser (in front of haproxy), http://host.com/myapp/myfile.html does not work.

I suppose that I can remove the /myapp from the path in haproxy on the backend, but is there a way with express that i can account for the base directory?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
app.use('/myapp/',express.static('static/public'));
```